# Python creating a mapping from a tuple

Tags: python

I want to make `def next(self, state: State) -> State` return `state.next(**{something})`.

When a new state is created each action, one at the time, updates the state. The `state.next` updates the state.

```
class Transition(object):
actions: Tuple[Action]

def next(self, state: State) -> State:
    return state.next(**{something})
```

When using `print(self.actions)` this is printed

> (Assign(variable='a', value_or_variable=False), Assign(variable='c', value_or_variable=True))

Hence, this *something* should be each element of actions. To clarify it should be something like:

```
state.next(**{'a' : False})
state.next(**{'c' : True})
```

A State contains of `dict[str, Any]`

Sorry if this is not information, but I would gladly send more if needed.

EDIT:
This is a solution to the problem, but is there any "smarter way to do this?

```
for x in self.actions:
    state = x.next(state)
return state
```

Comment: Could you format your indentation correctly and add the state class's def.?  Where is 'something' coming from?  `self.actions`?

Comment: It really looks like `State` would be better off as a subclass of dict, and `actions` as a list of dicts. Then updating would be dead simple. I imagine there are other constraints in your project that make this infeasible?

Comment: In response to your edit: actions are just namedtuples, right? What does an action's `next` method do?

Comment: Maybe *something* is confusing, but something was intended to be "here something should be"

Comment: Action is a protocol with a method called next, which is also implemented for several other objects in Action. The Assign class has a method called next which assigns the given value to the variable

Comment: I would think very carefully about where you want to keep your business logic. If states, transitions, and actions all have `next` methods that call each other, it seems like this could probably be better organized to cut down on repetition. It's hard to say from what you've shown, though.